# CS-Cart: integrating Fishbowl

Tags: cs-cart, inventory-management, warehouse

I am developing a cs-cart based website and my client wants to integrate [Fishbowl](https://www.fishbowlinventory.com/) into his website.
I have searched an add-on for it, but there is no one for me.
I have experience developed a simple add-on and, now I am going to build one add-on to integrate fishbowl.

Please guide me if you have solid experience on integrating fishbowl and cs-cart or another warehouse solution for cs-cart.

I don't understand why the fishbowl doesn't provide or developed the add-on for it.

Please help!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few things to watch out for, and therefore a number of options.

Firstly, what does your client really want. Does he want the stock to be updated on the fly, or once a night? If the client wants to stock to be updated on the fly you will need to add some sort of post function for updating products to also execute your code. If your client wants it only once a night you could just get away by sending every product in the database (with your selected columns).

Secondly, try using object oriented code. If you are really into PHP you will know what I mean by this. Otherwise dont bother (or try learing PHP Object Oriented), though I must note that this can make your addon significantly faster.

Thirdly, use the provided dbquery function

If you have any more questions regarding this, feel free to ask.